# How to make a web page fit after being transformed -90 deg in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page which I have rotated to -90 deg.

The page appears to look fine but it has the same width and height and in -90 deg mode white spaces appear.

I need to know how can i re-size the new height and width in the rotated web page.

I tried applying the css width and height to 100% but nothing seems to work.

The web page contains canvas element which means they need to be re-sized also.

The environment is chrome and UA -iOS4
Scripting Language -Javascript

Comment: You are rotating a web page by 90 degrees by default? May I ask why? That sounds awfully stressful to the client. Also show some code - if you use media queries, you just put the resizing instructions in there as well

Comment: I am viewing an application that displays some information in graphical form on canvas for that I am currently scrolling top to bottom.

Comment: I want to see the same information from left to right, so I rotated the div that was containing the info

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take old height and width then rotate and width=oldheight, height=oldwidth.